# WSO2 ESB - Dynamic value for proxy parameters (transport)

Tags: proxy, wso2, mediator, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I need to be able to specify a dynamic value for proxy parameter. Actually, I have to specify each parameter with complete URL like :

```
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.txt</parameter>
```

I see some samples with property mediator and I guess it's working for next proxies but the problem here is that I need to change the proxy parameters value before its execution I think. I tried with a "trigger" proxy calling a custom mediator which change SynapseConfiguration of required proxy but this wasn't working.

Is there a way to replace these fixed value with lookups to create some deployment configuration ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Parameters in the Proxy service definitions are service level Parameters which is in the Axis2Service Configuration . They are used when you are initialing the Axis2Service in this case its the Synapse/WSO2 ESB proxy service. So you can't change the parameters dynamically on the fly.

But i can suggest following approach. It might or might not applicable to your scenario.

Have set of VFS proxies that listen for separate locations. Each will look at a give file extension. (one for .txt one for .foo etc..)

Use another generic vfs proxy to copy files to correct places dynamically(which accepts any extension).(You can use vfs sender).

Hope this helps.

cheers,
Charith

Comment: Thank you for answering.

I tried to do a "trigger" proxy with custom mediator (always running) to change conf. of other proxies. Something like this :

`ProxyService proxy = mc.getConfiguration().getProxyService(proxyName);
Map<String, Object> parameters = proxy.getParameterMap();
if(proxy.isRunning()){
    proxy.stop(mc.getConfiguration());
}
proxy.getParameterMap().put("transport.vfs.FileURI","..");
proxy.start(mc.getConfiguration());`

Apparently the proxy is stopping and restarting, but modification aren't taken (don't know why). Can it be a possible workaround ?

Regards,

Loïc

Answer (score 2):

You can check out this post [How to dynamically route message in WSO2 ESB based on XML configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034013/how-to-dynamically-route-message-in-wso2-esb-based-on-xml-configuration-file/11081687#11081687) for an example how to dynamically set values in a proxy sequence.

You can do something this:

```
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">
    <script language="js">mc.getProperty('MY_DYNAMIC_VALUE')</script>
</parameter>
```

I am not sure this will help you much, as I suspect that the vfs parameters are set when initializing the proxy and not on the fly. If you give it a try,  if possible please post back to this thread if it works or not.

Regards, nidkil

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tested but it does not work. The sample with script mediator is accessing a property which has been defined with a property mediator before. It's strange that no feature is available to easily create dynamic configuration. Regards, Loïc

Comment: This answer does not work - the parameter will be set to the full <script language ... You cannot use script here.